# Logback SMTPAppender cannot find JNDI location and start

Tags: java, jndi, logback, context.xml, smtpappender

Using `logback-1.0.13.jar` and JDK 1.6u34.

I have a Java web app (WAR) with the following `WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="5 minutes">
    <appender name="logManager-smtpAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>

        <sessionViaJNDI>true</sessionViaJNDI>
        <jndiLocation>java:comp/env/mail/Session-local</jndiLocation>

        <subject>%logger{20} - %m</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
        <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
            <bufferSize>25</bufferSize>
        </cyclicBufferTracker>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="logManager-smtpAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And the following `${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/context.xml` (global `context.xml` for all web apps):

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource
        name="mail/Session-local"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.smtp.host="my.smtp.server"
        mail.user="smtp_user"
        mail.password="smtp_password"
        mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
        mail.smtp.auth="true"
        mail.smtp.port="25"
        mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
    />
</Context>
```

And have the [Java Mail API 1.4.3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.mail|mailapi|1.4.3|jar) (which I have verified contains a `javax.mail.Authenticator` class) on my runtime classpath at `WEB-INF/lib/javax-mail-1.4.3.jar`). I also have it in Tomcat's lib directory (`${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib`).

And am getting the following stack trace:

```
13:34:09,178 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
13:34:09,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
13:34:09,181 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/myuser/sandbox/dsi/workbench/tomcat/6.0.32/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
13:34:09,469 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 5 minutes
13:34:09,470 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/home/myuser/sandbox/dsi/workbench/tomcat/6.0.32/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]] every 300 seconds. 
13:34:09,470 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
13:34:11,782 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender]
13:34:11,830 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [logManager-smtpAppender]
13:34:11,939 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Looking up javax.mail.Session at JNDI location [java:comp/env/mail/Session-local]
13:34:11,992 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Failed to obtain javax.mail.Session from JNDI location [java:comp/env/mail/Session-local]
13:34:11,992 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Failed to obtain javax.mail.Session. Cannot start.
13:34:11,993 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ALL
13:34:11,996 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [logManager-smtpAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
13:34:11,997 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
13:34:12,000 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@63220fd1 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
13:39:49,988 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Attempted to append to non started appender [logManager-smtpAppender].
13:39:49,988 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Attempted to append to non started appender [logManager-smtpAppender].
13:39:50,598 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Attempted to append to non started appender [logManager-smtpAppender].
13:39:51,275 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Attempted to append to non started appender [logManager-smtpAppender].
13:39:51,833 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Attempted to append to non started appender [logManager-smtpAppender].
```

Any ideas as to why Logback can't retrieve my JNDI Mail Session from Tomcat's `context.xml`? This is preventing the SMTPAppender from starting and being able to log messages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't put the mail JAR in both locations, but in Tomcat's lib folder. If you are using Maven, use `provided` scope for the corresponding `<dependency />` to not package it in the WAR.

Second, do you have a `<resource-ref />` element for the mail session in your `web.xml`? If not, look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions) for a sample.

Another alternative is to make the session `<resource />` global (in `server.xml`) and link to it from the `context.xml`, as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource%20Links).

HTH,
Jukka

Comment: Thanks @Jukka (+1) - it was the duplicate mail jars after all!